# `email` field in exp_comment_subscription table

Tags: comments, hook

I disabled the sending of notifications for comments because I created a custom solution that triggers when a user makes a comment.

I am trying to get emails of the subscribers via the exp_comment_subscription table.

Normally, I would just connect the dots via the `member_id` but I think I need to know what the `email` field does before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email` field is used for guest comments only. For registered and logged in members who comment, that field will be `NULL`. So for a given `entry_id`, you need to gather email addresses from the `exp_members` table, as well as any values from the `email` column if your site allows guests to comment.